# Firebase NextJs Expected first argument to collection() to be a CollectionReference

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, next.js

```
const [stablesValue, stablesLoading, stablesError] = useCollection(
  collection(db, 'stables'),
  {
    snapshotListenOptions: { includeMetadataChanges: true },
  }
);
```

This snippet of code is causing an error

> FirebaseError: [code=invalid-argument]: Expected first argument to collection() to be a CollectionReference, a DocumentReference or FirebaseFirestore

I can't seem to get why this is occuring and tried reading other stackoverflow threads but have not found any soulution to it yet.

db is exported from my other file like this.

```
export const db = getFirestore(app)
```

Comment: Can you `console.log(db)` right before `useCollection()` and share a screenshot of the output?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.